# WPF Change ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility with trigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="listView"/>
```

Is it possible to change `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility`

with

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
  <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" TargetName="listView" Value="Hidden" />
  </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

How to do it in correct way?

Comment: This might help if you're willing to do it in code behind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614954/how-to-manipulate-an-implicit-scrollbar-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

What the "correct way" of doing this is of course depends on your requirements. But you can refer to the following sample markup that uses a ToggleButton to display and hide the scrollbar of the ListView:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="listView">
            <ListView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListView">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Style>
        </ListView>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btn" Content="Enabled/Disable" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This works just fine provided that the ToggleButton and the ListView are in the same namescope. Othwerwise you better handle the Click event of the Button and set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` attached property of the ListView programmatically:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(listView, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);
}
```

XAML is a *markup* language after all. It is not intended to be used as a programming language where you implement fairly advanced logic. Use a programming language such as C# to do this :)